# Find the weighted sum of cosines from a weighted sum of sines

Tags: trigonometry

I have computed a quantity $p$

$p = \sum_{i=0}^{N}w_i sin(x_i)$

Now I have to compute $q$, where $q$ is

$q = \sum_{i=0}^{N}w_i cos(x_i)$

I am trying to see if I can save some computation while computing $q$.

Is there any quick way to compute $q$ utilizing $p$ (or any intermediate values while I compute $p$) without having to compute $q$ by finding individual cosine values and weighting and adding them?

Comment: Try a simple example. If you know $\sin x+\sin y=1$, what do you know about $\cos x+\cos y$? [Answer: almost nothing]

Comment: Any thoughts on my comment?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought it through and it looks like I can't reuse any computation here.

Comment: Good. You could try writing up an answer, and posting it.